# Symmetric Matrix for Elliptic Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, be an open and bounded domain with. Then a general second order elliptic equation is
$$-\sum_{i,j=1}^d\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\Big{(}a_{ij}(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\Big{)}+\sum_{i=1}^db_i(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}+c(x)u=f(x)$$
For continuously differentiable function $u:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we have 
$$\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}\ \ \ \ \ i,j=1,\cdots ,d$$

Now the book says that because of this we can assume the matrix $a_{ij}$ as symmetric.
I don't understand how this happening? Like how can we construct that matrix and show its symmetric property? So, can anyone show me with an example how to construct this matrix or provide some reading reference to get this clear?

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the divergence term you get

$$-\sum_{i,j=1}^d a_{ij}u_{x_ix_j} +\sum_{i=1}^d \tilde{b_i}(x)u_{x_i} + c(x)u$$

where

$$\tilde{b}_i(x) = b_i(x)-\sum_{j=1}^d \frac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial x_j}.$$

By the equality of mixed partials we can write this as

$$-\sum_{i=1}^d a_{ii}u_{x_ix_i} -\sum_{1 \leq i < j\leq d} (a_{ij} + a_{ji})u_{x_ix_j} +\sum_{i=1}^d \tilde{b_i}(x)u_{x_i} + c(x)u.$$

Hence, if we define a new matrix $\tilde{a}$ by

$$\tilde{a_{ij}} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{ij} + a_{ji})$$

then $\tilde{a}$ is symmetric and our original PDE is equivalent to

$$-\sum_{i,j=1}^d \tilde{a_{ij}}u_{x_ix_j} +\sum_{i=1}^d \tilde{b_i}(x)u_{x_i} + c(x)u.$$

You can put this back in divergence form by changing $b$ again if you like.

Comment: Can you write this in Matrix form? Like the matrix notation for above

Comment: What do you mean by Matrix form? This is the same notation as you used in the problem statement. In matrix form $\sum_{i,j=1}^d a_{ij}u_{x_ix_j} = \text{Trace}(AD^2u)$.

Comment: I mean the array form